# 'Catch is unreachable because no calls to throwing functions', but function is throwing errors?

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

It's likely that I will receive an SSL error -1200 from an Alamofire request, if this occurs, I want to output the error to a text field.

I'm trying to catch the error I'm getting in my console window so that I can output it to the text field, but I'm getting this message from xcode:

```
'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block
```

Here is how I'm structuring the do/try/catch with the AF request:

```
do{
       try AF.request(host, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:JSONEncoding.default)
           .responseData{ response in
               guard let responseData = response.data else { return }
               let responseJSON = try? JSON(data:responseData)
               if let responseJSONAsString = responseJSON?.rawString(){
                     self.output(text: responseJSONAsString + "\n\n\n")
               }
            }
}
catch {
        self.textField.stringValue = ("Caught: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
 AF.request(host, method: .post, parameters:parameters,encoding:JSONEncoding.default)
    .responseData { response in
        do {
            guard let responseData = response.data else { return }
            let responseJSON = try JSON(data:responseData)
            if let responseJSONAsString = responseJSON.rawString(){
                ///
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting this error now: 'Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(DataResponse<Data>) -> Void''

Comment: try to nest do/catch inside the alamofire callback see edit

Comment: I've done it exactly as you've stated. I'm getting the SSL error come through in my xcode console still but it's not coming from the catch statement like I need it to so that I can use the error.localizedDescription. I've tried just getting it to print anything in the catch, to see if it's entering the catch block, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire does not `throw` errors – that's what the error says – but you should handle the passed error in the closure

```
AF.request(host, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: .default)
   .responseData { response in
       switch response.result {
       case .success(let data):
           do {
               let responseJSON = try JSON(data: data)
               if let responseJSONAsString = responseJSON?.rawString(){
                   self.output(text: responseJSONAsString + "\n\n\n")
               }
           } catch {
               self.textField.stringValue = ("Caught:", error.localizedDescription)
           }
       case .failure(let error): 
           self.textField.stringValue = ("Network Error:", error.localizedDescription)
       }
}
```